# What is pseudo-hooks in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am a newbie in drupal world and  sometimes I see the word pseudo-hooks. What is pseudo-hooks means? What is the difference between hooks and pseudo-hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no source for this, but I think pseudo-hooks refer to those hooks that can only be implemented by a module that implements another, different hook first.

For example, back in Drupal 6 we had [`hook_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21node.php/function/hook_access/6), which could only be implemented (successfully, anyway) by modules that first implement [`hook_node_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!node.php/function/hook_node_info/6) to define a node type.

A similar example for Drupal 7 might be [`hook_field_is_empty()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7). Implementing that hook only makes sense (and indeed will only be invoked) if the same module implements [`hook_field_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7) in the first instance.

That might be wrong, but I've definitely seen the phrase used when talking about node API and field API hooks, so it's worth a stab at a guess.